# What database to use for my Electron offline Application

Tags: javascript, json, electron

I'm about to choose a suitable local database for my offline ElectronJS application. The Desktop App must add/update/delete/retrieve data from JSON files locally. the database structure is as follows :

```
{
  'data':[
    {
      'day':1344546000,
      'transactions':[
         {'time':'blabla', 'value1':'100',...},
         {'time':'blabla', 'value1':'100',...},
         {'time':'blabla', 'value1':'100',...},
      ]
    },
    {
      'day':1344546000,
      'transactions':[
         {'time':'blabla', 'value1':'100',...},
         {'time':'blabla', 'value1':'100',...},
         {'time':'blabla', 'value1':'100',...},
      ]
    },
    ....

  ]
}
```

This data must be placed locally in json file/files, so if the user closed the app and open it again the data should be retrieved.

each `day` object will have less than 500 transactions a day

Comment: You can use any storage mechanism supported by the browser **or** Node - consider localStorage or roll your own by [just saving files with `fs`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939289/easy-way-to-store-json-under-node-js). Is there any specific issue you have with the implementation or a concern you have?

Comment: I can use Node.JS, Express.JS and the front end would make http calls with paramets to put/delete/update/get the data, but for my purpose is this the right solution ( time spent coding, etc ), because this way its kinda clientside / serverside and why would i need serverside if the app is completely offline and i store the transactions locally

Answer (score 9):

I would go for PouchDB: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb

> PouchDB was created to help web developers build applications that
>   work as well offline as they do online.

NeDB looks also very promising: https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb

> Embedded persistent or in memory database for Node.js, nw.js, Electron
>   and browsers, 100% JavaScript, no binary dependency. API is a subset
>   of MongoDB's and it's plenty fast.

Comment: NeDB has not had much progress from the lack of commits for some time, are there any other recommendations?