# Is there any module that supports object modelling in NodeJS and Express based on JSON files?

Tags: json, node.js, express, models

This may be a naive question or a requirement. I parse huge raw data and restructure it into a set of JSON files. These JSON files reside in a directory). I would like to avoid setting up any NoSql database such as - MongoDB (any database for that matter)

Based on these JSON files, I would like to setup express models so that I can make queries to JSON files. There won't be any Create, Update, and Delete operations user will perform.

I was looking for a module similar to mongoose which can make things simpler.

Comment: I haven't heard of a module that does this, but I think it's because reading/writing JSON in node is simple in general. You could in theory write a helper file with functions that speed this process up?

Comment: Also, some interesting solutions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939289/easy-way-to-store-json-under-node-js